# RegisterWindowMessage Possible values

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, windows-messages

Maybe I am just missing some silly link on the MSDN, but I cannot seem to find the list of possible values [RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947(v=vs.85).aspx)() can take

The only one I can find is "WM_HTML_GETOBJECT". I found this on [pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/oleacc.objectfromlresult).
This however, I believe this crashes my application because what I am trying to get is an [IHTMLDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752691(v=vs.85).aspx) and not a [IHTMLDocument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752641(v=vs.85).aspx)

I have looked at

[Message Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468869(v=vs.85).aspx)

[Message Constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468871(v=vs.85).aspx)

[SendMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx)

[OCM_BASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644929(v=vs.85).aspx)

[WM_USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx)

[A google search for RegisterWIndowMessage list of possible values](https://www.google.com/search?q=RegisterWIndowMessage%20list&oq=RegisterWIndowMessage%20list&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=high#safe=strict&q=RegisterWIndowMessage%20list%20of%20possible%20messages)

[Another google search for send message types](https://www.google.com/search?q=SendMessage&oq=SendMessage&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=high#safe=strict&q=SendMessage%20types)

Maybe I am searching for the wrong things, but I sure can't find it.

My application fails here:

```
 Dialog =    (IHTMLDialog)ObjectFromLresult(lRes, typeof(IHTMLDialog).GUID, IntPtr.Zero);
```

However I believe the issue happened further up the pipeline up here :

```
  uint iMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");
```

Because this is not an HTML document, but actually a dialog.

If it helps I am getting the hwnd to the dialog this way :

```
   IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame", "Google -- Webpage Dialog");
```

Here is the full snippet of what I am trying to do if it helps :

```
        UIntPtr lRes;
        IHTMLDialog Dialog;  
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("Internet Explorer_TridentDlgFrame", "Google -- Webpage Dialog");
        uint iMsg = RegisterWindowMessage("WM_HTML_GETOBJECT");

        if (SendMessageTimeout(hwnd, iMsg, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, SendMessageTimeoutFlags.SMTO_ABORTIFHUNG, 1000, out lRes) == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("operation failed");
        }
        else
        {
            Dialog =   (IHTMLDialog)ObjectFromLresult(lRes, typeof(IHTMLDialog).GUID, IntPtr.Zero);

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[RegisterWindowMessage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644947.aspx) takes a string argument. You can pass **any** string value. If you are registering messages for your application, make sure to use unique string values (e.g. string representations of GUIDs).

Other than that, there is no complete list of string values you can pass, because any application can choose to register its own set of messages. You will have to consult the documentation that comes with those applications to find out, which messages it supports (if any).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that for me. So the string itself is not important as long as the application supports it? That means my code is failing at ObjectFromLresult for some other reason. I will investigate and ask a separate question as necessary.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: It is not clear, what you are trying to accomplish. `RegisterWindowMessage` is *"typically used to register messages for communicating between two cooperating applications."* The example you used was [introduced with IE 4](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/249232/). It may no longer be supported. But what are you ultimately trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to get programmatic access to a modal dialog that is loaded in a page in a web browser control.

Comment: I can get the hwnd, but converting it to an HTMLDialog/IHTMLDialog is what I am trying to do here.

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: That appears to be the wrong approach. If you need to automate a UI, [UI Automation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747327.aspx) would be a primary candidate for evaluation.

Comment: Okay, cool! Know any good tutorials on it or a good starting point?

Comment: @AlexanderRyanBaggett: I'm sure there are, but I wouldn't know of any. The link I posted has a pretty decent introduction. You'll know where to look next once you're done with that.